# Problems with rank as a method to select top-n rows from a group, deal with duplicated rank-values

Tags: sql

The SQL-query below returns 10 rows from each group based on rank(). However, one problem is that two rows can have the same rank and therefore returning eleven rows in on group. I'm not very skilled in SQL and have searched the web for a better solution but haven't found anyone I understand. I wonder about ways to force the query to return only 10 rows per group and perhaps diffrent methods about how to deal with duplicates in rank().

```
with lan as(
            select period, nya, lan_.lan_beskr, SSYK2012, 
                                case when substr(period,6,2) in ('01','02','03') then substr(period, 1,4) || '_1'
                                when substr(period,6,2) in ('04','05','06') then substr(period, 1,4) || '_2'
                                when substr(period,6,2) in ('07','08','09') then substr(period, 1,4) || '_3' 
                                else substr(period, 1,4) || '_4' end kvartal
                                from SQL_view pl
                                left outer join dwman.vf_lan lan_
                                on substr(pl.kommun,1,2)=lan_.lan_kod
                                where  lan_.lan_beskr is not null and nya> 0 and SSYK2012 is not null
                                and PERIOD > to_char(add_months(sysdate, -24), 'YYYY-MM')),
                                
t1 as (select kvartal, lan_beskr, SSYK2012, count(nya) as antal from lan
                group by kvartal, LAN_BESKR, SSYK2012
                order by kvartal, count(nya) DESC)
    
select kvartal, lan_beskr, SSYK2012, antal, RANK
FROM ( select kvartal, lan_beskr, SSYK2012, antal, Rank()
over (partition by kvartal, lan_beskr ORDER BY antal DESC) as RANK
FROM t1)
where RANK <=10
```

Comment: maybe you can use dense_rank instead, this will always result in consecutive rankings

Comment: @MarELL But the result can still be two rows with rank 10 when using dense_rank() as I understand it?

Comment: If you need all different  numbers use `row_number()` instead. `Rank` and `dense_rank` will return the same number for the same value.

Comment: @Serg In my query I first do a group by to calculate the sum of each group (kvartal, LÄN_BESKR, SSYK2012). Then I go back on level during partition (kvartal, LAN_BESKR) when I rank. I guess row_number() would have to be done before the group by then?

Comment: I see no data an can't say it for sure but try just to replace rank with row_number.